# wget script, but pipe it to bash only if SHA256 of script matches one-liner

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, wget

`wget http://example.com/install.sh -O - | bash` runs the script automatically but due to possible (TLS) MITM attacks etc, this is not safe. Is is possible to construct a one-liner that downloads the script, but executes it only if it's hash matches the one specified in the one-liner? It would be nice if the one-liner would print something like `Warning! Hash mismatch` if hash check fails.

Comment: The first step would be to take out the pipe to bash. The second step would be to prompt you to input the valid SHA256 code. The third step to generate off the file. The fourth to either run the script or give an error message. One line makes it more difficult to read and debug than 10 lines.

Comment: The reason one-liner for piping is needed, is to minimize the time system remains connected to network. The hash in one-liner must come from trusted source same way a PGP public key fingerprint would have to so there's no need to type it manually. The one-liner will be copy-pasted by user so readability is secondary.

Comment: How do you plan to obtain the hash sum for verification? Can you elaborate that a bit, please? What information can we get from local files and what can we obtain remotely? Comparing the downloaded file with a locally stored hash sum and then executing it after successful verification is doable in one line. But I am not sure how much additional verification you want to securely obtain a hash.

Comment: The root of trust can be presented in person. [Qubes project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0TVw7U3MkE#t=45m30s) for example. I understand this is key fingerprint instead of hash, so the question above doesn't actually fully suit my needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you want to download and run `http://example.com/install.sh`.

For now I assume that you have its SHA256 hash stored locally in a file called `my-sha256.txt`. The file contains only the hash itself and a Unix-style linebreak character, so its size must be exactly 65 bytes. You can create it by simply running this:

```
sha256sum ORIGINAL_FILE.SH | grep -Eo '^\w+' > my-sha256.txt
```

How you distribute this hash file from your development machine to the client is not part of this answer (yet, you might clarify your question and ask me to update this part based on your detailed specifications).

---

The actual command your client has to run to download, verify, and on success execute the script could look like this:

```
t=$(mktemp) && wget 'http://example.com/install.sh' -qO "$t" && if sha256sum "$t" | grep -Eo '^\w+' | cmp -s my-sha256.txt ; then bash "$t" ; else echo FAIL ; fi ; rm "$t"
```

Slightly shortened and ugly version without whitespace:

```
t=$(mktemp)&&wget 'http://example.com/install.sh' -qO"$t"&&if sha256sum "$t"|grep -Eo '^\w+'|cmp -s my-sha256.txt;then bash "$t";else echo FAIL;fi;rm "$t"
```

Placed on multiple lines for readability:

```
t=$(mktemp) && 
wget 'http://example.com/install.sh' -qO "$t" && 
if sha256sum "$t" | grep -Eo '^\w+' | cmp -s my-sha256.txt 
    then bash "$t" 
    else echo FAIL 
fi 
rm "$t"
```

If you want to directly provide the hash inside the command as string instead of reading from a file, simply use one of my original command versions above and replace the occurrence of `my-sha256.txt` with `<(echo YOUR_HASH)`, inserting your real hash instead of the "YOUR_HASH" placeholder of course.

**Explanation:**

The script/one-liner first creates a temporary file using `mktemp` (uses the system's temp folder `/tmp`).
Then it uses `wget` to download your installation script from the specified URL and save it in the temp file.
Now we calculate its hash sum, filter only the hash value from the output of `sha256sum` and compare that to what we have stored in out `my-sha256.txt`.
If both hashes equal, we will invoke `bash` with our temporary script file as argument, else we `echo FAIL` or you could output a custom error message.
In the end we clean up by deleting our temporary file in both cases.

---

However, coming back to the problem of securely distributing the hash to verify the original script, this solution above will not help you much, as it solves one problem by creating another one of the same kind.

What you actually should do is to create a GPG key pair (and publish your public key to a keyserver), sign your script with it and offer the compressed signed binary for download. Then let the client verify and decrypt the script using `gpg` again and run it on success.

Comment: This works great! I noticed that your unshortened one-liner greps `'^\w+ '` instead of `'^\w+'`, which doesn't work. The only thing missing for my needs is specifying the SHA256 hash from within the one-liner. Is there a cleaner way to do this than `h=$(mktemp); t=$(mktemp); echo '14b652ef7e7a5b3ae92351ee9695bce956a904db562f16a7c48cfcd3f4b7c937' > $h; wget 'https://example.com/install.sh' -qO "$t" && if sha256sum "$t" |grep -Eo '^\w+' |cmp -s $h ; then bash "$t" ; else echo ERROR: Invalid SHA256 hash ; fi ; rm "$t"; rm "$h";` ?

Comment: My case has a race condition for system compromise from the point user downloads install.sh to the point install.sh kills network interfaces. Manual program/key/signature download, key import, signature verification, unzipping, navigation and execution of install.sh wastes a lot of time. The SHA256 one-liner adds trust between downloads, but changes for each version of my program. So I prob need a one-liner with pinned PGP fingerprint that downloads and imports key, compares fingerprint and then downloads install.sh and it's signature, verifies file, and then pipes install.sh to bash.

Comment: @maqp Thanks for paying attention, I fixed the wrong space in some of my `grep`s. If you want to directly provide the hash inside the command as string instead of reading from a file, simply use my original command and replace the occurrence of `my-sha256.txt` with `<(echo 14b652ef7e7a5b3ae92351ee9695bce956a904db562f16a7c48cfcd3f4b7c937)` literally. You don't need to make a temporary file like your proposed approach did.

Comment: @maqp I still don't fully understand what your real goal is and why you set yourself such uncommon  restrictions. Maybe it would be helpful if you could share the bigger picture of what you are going to do? I can also only recommend you to visit the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), it is probably easier to have a quick dialogue for clarification there and get input from many people there.

Comment: The bigger picture is a [project](https://github.com/maqp/tfc) I'm working on. The transmitter device requires minimal exposure to network to minimize the window of exposure during which remote exploitation can defeat security provided by the entire system. Hence the restrictions. So a one liner containing publicly trusted key fingerprint that downloads necessary files, verifies installer with PGP and pipes it to bash if PGP signature is ok, is what's currently missing.

Comment: I think I got it: `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys <GPG pub key SHA1 fingerprint> && wget https://example.com/install.sh{,.asc} -q && gpg --verify install.sh{.asc,} && bash install.sh`

Comment: @maqp Maybe you want to post that as a separate answer for better readability? The limited formatting options in comments make it a bit difficult here.

Answer (score 0):

Since GPG fingerprints use [insecure SHA-1 hash](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014.pdf), here is a one-liner that allows authentication with unofficial SHA256 hash calculated from public key with

`gpg --export <key ID> | sha256sum`

command:

`h="<SHA256 hash of exported public key>"; fp="<PGP key SHA1 fingerprint>"; f='key.pub'; gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv $fp && gpg --export $fp > $f && if sha256sum $f | grep -Eo '^\w+' | cmp -s <(echo $h); then rm $f && wget https://example.com/install.sh{,.asc} -q && gpg --verify install.sh{.asc,} && bash install.sh; else rm $f; echo "ERROR: Signing key had invalid SHA256 hash"; fi;`